# Configure Apache NiFi StandardRestrictedSSLContextService Controller Service

Tags: ssl, https, apache-nifi, tls1.2

In NiFi, how does one create the necessary keystore, truststore and certificates needed to configure the StandardRestrictedSSLContextService controller service?

I need to invoke an HTTPS REST service.  (Using NiFi 1.9.2 in local development mode)

Steps taken:

1. Used TLS toolkit to generate self-signed certs, truststore and keystore
2. Saved the API endpoint certificate to a .cer file (exported from chrome)
3. `$keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore /opt/nifi/conf/truststore.jks -file api-cert.cer`

After doing this, InvokeHTTP processor in NiFi indicates it cannot find the certification path:
`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Answer (score 1):

You can either create those files manually (using tools like `openssl` and `keytool`), use the [NiFi TLS Toolkit](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#tls_toolkit), or obtain those files from an enterprise security team. The keystore needs to contain the private key and public certificate of the NiFi certificate; the truststore should contain the public certificates of the external services you want to interact with. See the [NiFi Walkthroughs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/walkthroughs.html#securing-nifi-with-tls) for examples. `RestrictedSSLContextService` is only required for incoming connections; `SSLContextService` can be used for outgoing connections to legacy systems (`Restricted` disables TLS protocol versions older than TLS v1.2).

Comment: Thanks Andy.  After trying out the steps, it looks like I'm still missing something.  I've updated the question under 'Steps taken'

Answer (score 0):

Provide a full path in the keystore and truststore filename fields.
I'm using a nifi contianer and the default directory is `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/`.

I placed the files in a **certs** directory so my keystore filename field looks like this:
`certs/keystore.pfx`